# How to separate application and data syncing implementations in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to build an application/service which uses a static application data which can get updated over time. Currently, I implemented this by having both the application and the data within the same container. However, this requires redeployment when either application or data change. I want to separate the app and data volume implementation so that I can update the application and the data independently, meaning I won't have to rebuild the application layer when the application data is updated and vice versa.

Here are the characteristics of the Application Data and its Usage:

- Data is **not frequently updated**, but **read very frequently** by the application
- Data is not a database, it's a collection of **file objects** with size ranging from 100MB to 4GB which is initially stored in a cloud storage
- Data stored in the cloud storage serves as a single source of truth for the application data
- The application will **only read** from the Data. The process of updating data in cloud storage is an external process outside the application scope.

So here, we are interested in sync-ing the data in cloud storage to the volume in Kubernetes deployment. What's the best way to achieve this objective in Kubernetes?

I have several options in mind:

1. Using one app container in one deployment, in which the app will also include the logic for data loading and update which pulls data 
   from cloud storage to the container --> simple but tightly coupled with the storage read-write implementation
2. Using the cloud store directly from the app --> this doesn't require container volume, but I was concerned with the huge file size because the app is an interactive service which requires a quick response
3. Using two containers in one deployment sharing the same volume --> allow great flexibility for the storage read-write implementation

   - one container for application service reading from the shared volume
   - one container for updating data and listening to update data request which writes data to the shared volume --> this process will pull data from cloud storage to the shared volume
4. Using one container with a Persistent Disk

   - an external process which writes to the persistent disk (not sure how to do this yet with cloud storage/file objects, need to find a way to sync gcs to persistent disk)
   - one container for application service which reads from the mounted volume
5. Using Fuse mounts

   - an external process which writes to cloud storage
   - a container which uses fuse mounts

I am currently leaning towards option 3, but I am not sure if it's the common practice of achieving my objective. Please let me know if you have better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 3. is the most common option but make sure you use an [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to copy the data from your cloud storage to a local volume. That local volume could be any of the [types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes) supported by Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was planning to use initContainer, but may I ask you follow-up questions? I think initContainer works best for initializing data into the local volume, but how about updating data after the application is up and running? Should I use 2 containers for syncing the data? One as an initContainer which populates data into the local volume at initial and another as a regular container which scheduled or receive ad-hoc requests to update data in the local volume after the app is running? Or is there a way to re-execute the initContainer with different params scheduled or ad hocly?

Comment: If you want to regularly sync, you can use another regular container. initcontainers don't actually stay running, they are just for 'initializing the pod'

Answer (score 0):

Option 5. might now be more interesting because in the meantime Google Cloud released their own [GCS Fuse driver](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) including [GKE specific integration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/cloud-storage-fuse-csi-driver). If you don't want to rewrite your application to use GCS APIs this could be a drop in replacement which fits well for a majority read workload like yours. It supports ranged reads so if your application only reads a small piece of a large file only the small piece will be fetched.

[Performance benchmarks](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/benchmarks.md) are available for you to verify if the latency is acceptable for your workload needs.